# Navbar dropdown shifts items out of the navbar when using small screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

[The image clearly depicts what i meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alEKd.png)

I am trying to shift it inside the navbar when using small screen but its not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Boostrap provides responsive menu alignment with the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment). By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the top and along the left side of its parent. To use responsive alignment, disable dynamic positioning by adding the data-bs-display="static" attribute and use the responsive variation classes.

Ex for small screen:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
    Left-aligned but right aligned when small screen
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm-end">
    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button></li>
    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button></li>
    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Other breakpoints `.dropdown-menu{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl}-end.`